# jqm-calendar time format (24 hour default...would prefer 12 hour)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, calendar

I am using jqm-calendar for my jquery mobile app.  Right now the default time format is 24 hours.  I would like to change it to 12 hours.

Thank you.

https://github.com/JWGmeligMeyling/jqm-calendar

Comment: can you post what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In file jw-jqm-cal.js

**add this function:**

```
  function tConvert (time) {
      // Check correct time format and split into components
      time = time.toString ().match (/^([01]\d|2[0-3])(:)([0-5]\d)(:[0-5]\d)?$/) || [time];

      if (time.length > 1) { // If time format correct
        time = time.slice (1);  // Remove full string match value
        time[5] = +time[0] < 12 ? ' AM' : ' PM'; // Set AM/PM
        time[0] = +time[0] % 12 || 12; // Adjust hours
      }
      return time.join (''); // return adjusted time or original string
}
```

**and insert this 2 lines**  in function *plugin.settings.eventHandler.getEventsOnDay(begin, end, function(list_of_events)*:

```
beginTime =tConvert(beginTime );
endTime=tConvert(endTime);
```

**EDIT**

**insert before:** timeString = beginTime + "-" + endTime :**

...

*beginTime =tConvert(beginTime );*

*endTime=tConvert(endTime);*

**timeString = beginTime + "-" + endTime,**

...

Comment: I put in the 2 lines under function plugin.settings.eventHandler.getEventsOnDay(begin, end, function(list_of_events).  http://jsfiddle.net/L9odmhvb/.  It didn't change anything.  Am i placing the code in the right spots?

Comment: insert before: timeString = beginTime + "-" + endTime

Comment: It wouldn't let me vote because I do not have enough rep points.  I will vote when I have enough.